# Is it possible to get the link address if given the uip address in Contiki-NG

Tags: ip-address, contiki, data-link-layer

I'm developing a project using Contiki-NG and I was working on something somehow similiar to a firewall.
I have a function that **receives** a **IP Address** (uip_ipaddr_t) and I was wondering if it is possible to **get the link address** (linkaddr_t ) of this mote, if it checked out to be a neighbor.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an IPv6 neighbor with a given IP address (`const uip_ipaddr_t *ipaddr`), then its simply a matter of calling this function:

```
const linkaddr_t *lla = (const linkaddr_t *)uip_ds6_nbr_lladdr_from_ipaddr(ipaddr);
```

See the [documentation](https://contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/develop/_api/group__uip.html#gaf3331a489128307594641c2b8a390c18) of `uip_ds6_nbr_lladdr_from_ipaddr()`.